# Create Date from Date plus Time

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I have a database that has a timestamp saved in two fields, one for the date (2015-04-22) and one for the time (11:45:00).

```
ResultSet rs = //db stuff
Date date = rs.getDate("date"); 
Time time = rs.getDate("time");
```

Now I want one date object with the date and time from those 2 objects.
How would I do that?

Comment: I have tried and failed to come up with a version using the new java.time API :-( If someone finds out how to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date dateTime = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 
    time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds());
```

Or not deprecated, **preffered** solution:

```
Calendar calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarDate.setTime(date);

Calendar calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarTime.setTime(time);

Calendar calendarDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendarDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, calendarTime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendarTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendarTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendarTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

Date dateTime = calendarDateTime.getTime();
```

Comment: date.getYear() and the others are deprecated. :(

Comment: That constructor is deprecated:  
@Deprecated
public Date(int year,
                        int month,
                        int date,
                        int hrs,
                        int min,
                        int sec)
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).

Comment: @Diskutant added not deprecated solution

Comment: I had a small error in my question, the time object needs to be of type Time instead of Date, else I get exceptions. Your code works but for some reason it adds 12 hours in the calendarDateTime object, but the time object shows the correct time. I already tried Calendar.HOUR and Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY. Any Idea what causes this?

Comment: @Diskutant Maybe you need to add `calendarDateTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use gregorian calendar:

```
public GregorianCalendar(int year,
             int month,
             int dayOfMonth,
             int hourOfDay,
             int minute,
             int second)
```

And excract the values from the `Date`s you got using getters:

```
Date.getYear()
Date.getMonth()
Date.getDay() 
Date.getHours()
Date.getMinutes()
Date.getSeconds()
```

Comment: those getters are deprecated

Comment: Oh, right! Alexander corrected his answer now, so I'd go with that!